# What is this schematic symbol in the INA851 overvoltage schematic?

Tags: identification, over-voltage-protection, differential-amplifier

I was looking at the [INA851](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina851.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A125%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2Cnull%2C464.875%2Cnull%5D) and trying to understand the input over-voltage protection. I can't seem to figure out what this pictured part is.

[image: Unkown Device]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like it's two depletion-mode FETs tied back-to-back.  If I'm reading the purpose of that correctly, it should look like a series resistor under normal circumstances, but source or draw a constant current to or from the input transistor base when the input voltage gets excessive.

So, basically, it looks like it's a protection circuit.

Answer (score 14):

It's part of the input port over-voltage protection on the INA851. Basically it acts as a current limiter should excessive over-voltage occur: -

[image]

So, a constant current diode (a real device) is made from an N-channel JFET and resistor like this: -

[image]

Because it will conduct as hard as it can in the "wrong" direction, two are used (back-to-back) in series: -

[image]

And, depending on the construction of the JFET, the resistor can be internal hence: -

[image]

And, of course they can be made from P-channel devices equally well (as the INA851 circuit indicates): -

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It looks like two [JFETs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JFET) tied together.